Finding the leftover rows in pandas dataframes
If I'm detecting Ys in particular columns using this:
thing1 = df[df['column1'] == 'Y']

thing2 = df[df['column2'] == 'Y']

thing3 = df[df['column3'] == 'Y']

thing4 = df[df['column4'] == 'Y']

How can I get all the rows that don't have Y in one of those columns?  I have tried something like:
none_of_the_things = df[(df['column1'] != 'Y') & (df['column2'] != 'Y') & (df[df['column3'] != 'Y']) & (df[df['column4'] != 'Y'])]

but this does not work.  With this sort of error:
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 23.3 TiB for an array with shape (1855862, 1724897) and data type float64
python ./deepseek-v2.5-chart.py  11.91s user 2.81s system 105% cpu 13.996 total

have I created some sort of monster with this method?  23.3 TiB sounds like a lot.
example csv:
RECVDATE,column1,column2,column3,column4
01/01/2024,Y,N,N,N
01/04/2024,N,N,N,N
02/02/2024,N,Y,N,N
02/02/2024,N,Y,N,N
02/04/2024,N,N,N,N
03/03/2024,N,N,Y,N
03/03/2024,N,N,Y,N
03/03/2024,N,N,Y,N
03/04/2024,N,N,N,N
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,Y
04/04/2024,N,N,N,N
04/04/2024,N,N,N,N

example python with the failing stuff commented out:
#!/usr/bin env python3
date_field = 'RECVDATE'
import glob, os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
dir_path = 'data'
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False, quotechar='"') for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, 'example.csv'))]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df[date_field] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_field], errors='coerce')

thing1 = df[df['column1'] == 'Y']
thing1['YearMonth'] = thing1[date_field].dt.to_period('M')
monthly_counts1 = thing1.groupby('YearMonth').size()
monthly_counts1.index = monthly_counts1.index.astype(str)

thing2 = df[df['column2'] == 'Y']
thing2['YearMonth'] = thing2[date_field].dt.to_period('M')
monthly_counts2 = thing2.groupby('YearMonth').size()
monthly_counts2.index = monthly_counts2.index.astype(str)

thing3 = df[df['column3'] == 'Y']
thing3['YearMonth'] = thing3[date_field].dt.to_period('M')
monthly_counts3 = thing3.groupby('YearMonth').size()
monthly_counts3.index = monthly_counts3.index.astype(str)

thing4 = df[df['column4'] == 'Y']
thing4['YearMonth'] = thing4[date_field].dt.to_period('M')
monthly_counts4 = thing4.groupby('YearMonth').size()
monthly_counts4.index = monthly_counts4.index.astype(str)

# none_of_the_things = df[(df['column1'] != 'Y') & (df['column2'] != 'Y') & (df[df['column3'] != 'Y']) & (df[df['column4'] != 'Y'])]
# none_of_the_things['YearMonth'] = none_of_the_things[date_field].dt.to_period('M')
# non_monthly_counts = none_of_the_things.groupby('YearMonth').size()
# non_monthly_counts.index = non_monthly_counts.index.astype(str)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
monthly_counts1.plot(kind='line', marker='o', label='count1', color='red')
monthly_counts2.plot(kind='line', marker='o', label='count2', color='blue')
monthly_counts3.plot(kind='line', marker='o', label='count3', color='green')
monthly_counts4.plot(kind='line', marker='o', label='count4', color='purple')
# non_monthly_counts.plot(kind='line', marker='o', label='none', color='black')
plt.title('Number of Deaths/LifeThreating/Hospitalizations per Month')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(title='Legend', loc='upper left')
plt.show()


I think you just made a typo. You have df[<col>] != 'Y' in the first two spots (correctly) but df[df[<col>] != 'Y'] in the second two spots.

Otherwise, please make a reproducible pandas example with example input and desired output.

I corrected the typo

and added example code and csv file

The typo is still there

Select applicable columns (here using df.filter), check equal to 'Y' with df.eq, chain df.any over axis=1, invert the resulting boolean series with ~ and use for boolean indexing:
out = df[~df.filter(like='column').eq('Y').any(axis=1)]

Output:
      RECVDATE column1 column2 column3 column4
1   01/04/2024       N       N       N       N
4   02/04/2024       N       N       N       N
8   03/04/2024       N       N       N       N
15  04/04/2024       N       N       N       N
16  04/04/2024       N       N       N       N

Given your example, it will be easier to do it the other way around, using df.all for equal to 'N':
out2 = df[df.filter(like='column').eq('N').all(axis=1)]

out2.equals(out)
# True

If your actual df doesn't have uniform column names, use df[['column1', 'column2', ...]].

From what I have observed in your code the problem might lie in this part:
none_of_the_things = df[(df['column1'] != 'Y') & (df['column2'] != 'Y') & (df[df['column3'] != 'Y']) & (df[df['column4'] != 'Y'])]

The issue with your code is that you had extra brackets inside the conditions, causing pandas to treat them as nested DataFrames.
Instead you should try this:
none_of_the_things = df[
    (df['column1'] != 'Y') &
    (df['column2'] != 'Y') &
    (df['column3'] != 'Y') &
    (df['column4'] != 'Y')
]

this will create dataframe from all the values in columns as I imagine it is intended to.
